# Safari 14.1.2 - Can't find variable: MediaRecorder

Tags: ios, safari, mediarecorder

According to https://caniuse.com/?search=mediarecorder  the MediaRecorder API has been supported by Safari and Safari on iOS since version 14. However when I try to use it I'm getting 'Can't find variable: MediaRecorder'

Am I instantiating this in the wrong way?  Here's a code snippet

```
              this.videoRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
                mimeType: "video/webm",
                audioBitsPerSecond: 128000
              });
```

and, for just audio

```
              this.audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
                audioBitsPerSecond: 128000
              });
```

Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that mediaRecorder is still an experimental feature that needs to be enabled on Safari on Mac OS. It's enabled on iOS, the problems I was having on that platform were unrelated.